# ArcGIS Pro Field Calculator Python IF statement

Tags: field-calculator, arcgis-pro, python-parser

I'm attempting to populate a newly created field with values dependent on an existing field.

The new field has text data type. The existing field is double data type. This is the python code I've been trying. It runs, but the values remain

```
def Reclass(Crime):
    if (Hierarchy == 1):
        return "Murder-Manslaughter"
    elif (Hierarchy == 2):
        return "Forcible Rape"
    elif (Hierarchy == 3):
        return "Robbery"
    elif (Hierarchy == 4):
        return "Aggravated Assault"
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the `Hierarchy` field to the function, not the `Crime` field.

```
crime = 
Reclass(!Hierarchy!)
```

```
def Reclass(Hierarchy):
    if (Hierarchy == 1):
        return "Murder-Manslaughter"
    elif (Hierarchy == 2):
        return "Forcible Rape"
    elif (Hierarchy == 3):
        return "Robbery"
    elif (Hierarchy == 4):
        return "Aggravated Assault"
```

Or even neater, use a `dict` lookup:

```
def Reclass(Hierarchy):
    reclass = {
        1: "Murder-Manslaughter",
        2: "Forcible Rape",
        3: "Robbery",
        4: "Aggravated Assault",
    }
    return reclass.get(Hierarchy)
```

Comment: Thanks!
Do you know of any good resources for learning python with GIS?

Comment: No, I picked it up as I went along. Try https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=learning+python

Comment: @BenD On Udemy there is ArcPy for Python Developers using ArcGIS Pro which is an eLearning course I wrote and recorded.